# How can I detect and parse from one of these string formats in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, string-parsing

I am writing a JavaScript function (no jQuery), which will receive a string with one of the following formats:

1. [Blah] [Read this] [Blah] [Optional blah]
2. [Blah] Read this [Blah] Optional blah

I want to pick the "Read this" string out of the rest. The "Optional blah" bits may or may not be present (along with the accompanying square brackets in the first case), but they shouldn't matter. Any ideas on how to write a function that does this?

Comment: Are you saying that the bit you want to read will always be surrounded by [blah]? ie. [blah]the bit I want to ready[blah]

Comment: @net.uk.sweet Yes. This is the exact format. Only content inside the brackets changes. Assume there won't be any square brackets in the Blah content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reg Exp will do the job :

```
var a = "[Blah] [Read this] [Blah] [Optional blah]";
var b = "[Blah] Read this [Blah] Optional blah";
var text1 = a.match(/\[[^\]]+\]\s*\[*([^\]\[]+)\]*\s*\[[^\]]+\]\s*(\[*[^\]]+\]*)*/)[1].trim();
var text2 = b.match(/\[[^\]]+\]\s*\[*([^\]\[]+)\]*\s*\[[^\]]+\]\s*(\[*[^\]]+\]*)/)[1].trim();

console.log(text1); // "Read this"
console.log(text2); // "Read this"
```

**Edit1**
If you want to know which format you have :

```
var a = "[Blah] [Read this] [Blah] [Optional blah]";
var b = "[Blah] Read this [Blah] Optional blah";
var text1 = a.match(/\[[^\]]+\]\s*(\[*([^\]\[]+)\]*)\s*\[[^\]]+\]\s*(\[*[^\]]+\]*)*/);
var text2 = b.match(/\[[^\]]+\]\s*(\[*([^\]\[]+)\]*)\s*\[[^\]]+\]\s*(\[*[^\]]+\]*)/);
var text1_value = text1[2].trim();
var text2_value = text2[2].trim();
var text1_is_A_format = (/\[[^\]]+\]/).test(text1[1]);
var text2_is_A_format = (/\[[^\]]+\]/).test(text2[1]);

console.log(text1_is_A_format ); // true
console.log(text1_value); // "Read this"
console.log(text2_is_A_format ); // false
console.log(text2_value); // "Read this"
```

(i added a `()` around "[Read this]" and checked if `[]` exist)

**Edit2**

Split string on an array of the items we need items

```
var a = "[Blah1] [Read this2] [Blah3] [Optional blah4]";
var re = new RegExp('(\\]\\s*\\[|\\s+\\[|\\]\\s+|\\[|\\])','g'); // Create reg exp (will be used 2 times)
var b = a.split(re); // Split array on every match
for(var i = b.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ // remove useless array items
// We are making a count down for because we remove items from the array
    if(b[i].length == 0 || b[i].match(re))
        b.splice(i, 1);
}
console.log(b); // Print : Array [ "Blah1", "Read this2", "Blah3", "Optional blah4" ]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I guess I should go ahead and learn RegExp. Would it be possible to account for potentially missing spaces between the elements like this? [Blah][Read this][Blah][Optional blah]. Also, some spaces may be present and some may not be in any string.

Comment: I already do. `\s` is a space, `\s*` is 1 or none space, and the trim on the end removes the space from a case of not having []. If there will be spaces inside the string, remove them after with `.replace`.

Comment: Hey, could you use regex magic to split all four components of the strings? That would be awesome. I already have a way to detect the format.

Comment: This was also added on the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will this work on both formats? Because the new RegExp does not look like either of the other ones. Man, I should really figure out regex. In case you're curious, I'm parsing post titles from http://reddit.com/r/AppHookup for a Pebble app.

Comment: Yes it will work for both formats. It will only failed on something like `[Blah1] Read t]his2 [Blah3] Optional blah4` because of the ']' on the center of the string we want to get. But i may missed something so keep testing it.

Comment: This is amazing work. Thanks a lot for the help! I'll credit you at http://github.com/Antrikshy/AppHookup-for-Pebble